# Linear homeomorphism implies a Schauder basis

Tags: functional-analysis

**Problem:** Let *S* be a Schauder basis of *H*. Let *L:H $\rightarrow$ H* be a linear homeomorphism. Show that *L(S)* is a Schauder basis.

L is a linear homeomorphism if it is one-to-one, linear, continuous, and continuous inverse.

A Schauder basis if it is linearly independent, and for every $ v \epsilon X$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a set of scalars $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ such that

$||v-(\alpha_1 v_1+...+\alpha_n v_n)||<\epsilon||$.

**Proof:** Since L is linear, we need to show that the it is independent which it is because it is one-to-one. Since L is continuous we also get the inequality that is above. Done?

Comment: I think your definition is wrong: normally we need $v=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k v_k$, that is, in your formulation, the $(\alpha_i)$ should be independent of the $\epsilon$.  What you've written would hold for any linearly independent set with dense span.

Comment: So my answer is wrong or correct?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Your *question* is wrong, never mind the answer.